# Not able to delete old record types Undo

Tags: apex, visualforce, data-loader, data

We are in the process of upgrading new changes to our Salesforce org.

For this we are mapping some old record types to the new ones and are using data loader for the same.

When we run a report on activities we see that no user has the old record types - but i can see few participant records that still have the old records.
The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.

Comment: Hi could you be more precise what exactly you want to achieve? Did you verify that those old records have any related record type? and what data is missing?

Comment: That's probably just a glitch, but you can't delete a record type if any profile, including site profiles, have the record type set as its default. Have you verified that none of your profiles still have that record type set as default?